# How to change a column heading by using a column alias in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to rename the header of query output as "year" instead of year(meeting_date)
Thanks :)

My query returns the desired output just want to change the column name

```
SELECT DISTINCT year(meeting_date) FROM appointment As year
```

My expected output column header as:

```
year
2016
2017
2018
```

I get output as:

```
year(meeting_date)
2016
2017
2018
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT year(meeting_date) year FROM appointment. Next.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped and finally I could run this query successfully: SELECT a.id_skill, YEAR(a.meeting_date) As year, s.skill,COUNT(*) as count FROM appointment a,skills_data s where YEAR(a.meeting_date) = '2018' and a.id_skill=s.id_skill and a.ap_status = 'complete' GROUP BY `id_skill` order by count DESC

Comment: If a non-aggregated column appears in the SELECT, then it should also appear in the GROUP BY. You get away with it in this instance, because a) your WHERE clause filters for a specific year, and b) there is (presumably) a functional dependency between a.id_skill and s.id_skill. Even so, it's best practice to ALWAYS include non-aggregated columns in the SELECT.

Comment: Yes! a) my WHERE clause filters for a specific year selected by user from dropdown values(YEAR), and b) by selecting one value of a unique primary key i.e. s.id_skill, the value of the other column a.id_skill have only one combination of values. So, I hope this query would be more accurate to fulfill grouping by non-aggregated column:-  SELECT a.id_skill, YEAR(a.meeting_date) As year, s.skill,COUNT(*) as count FROM appointment a,skills_data s where YEAR(a.meeting_date) ='".$_POST["year"]."' and a.id_skill=s.id_skill and a.ap_status = 'complete' GROUP BY `id_skill`, 'year' order by count DESC

Comment: Note that 'year' is a string constant. \`year\` is a column alias

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for correcting. I got to learn more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
`SELECT DISTINCT year(meeting_date) As year FROM appointment`

Answer (score 1):

It will work this way. You need to add `As` after the column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT year(meeting_date) AS year FROM appointment;
```